# Lag() with condition in sql server

Tags: sql-server, lag, lead

i have a table like this:

```
Number   Price    Type       Date         Time
------   -----    ----    ----------    ---------
23456    0,665     SV     2014/02/02     08:00:02
23457    1,3       EC     2014/02/02     07:50:45
23460    0,668     SV     2014/02/02     07:36:34
```

For each EC I need previous/next SV price. In this case, the query is simple.

```
Select Lag(price, 1, price) over (order by date desc, time desc),
Lead(price, 1, price) over (order by date desc, time desc)
from ITEMS
```

But, there are some special cases where two or more rows are EC type:

```
Number   Price    Type       Date         Time
------   -----    ----    ----------    ---------
23456    0,665     SV     2014/02/02     08:00:02
23457    1,3       EC     2014/02/02     07:50:45
23658    2,4       EC     2014/02/02     07:50:45
23660    2,4       EC     2014/02/02     07:50:48
23465    0,668     SV     2014/02/02     07:36:34
```

can I use Lead/Lag in this cases? If not, did I have to use a subquery?

Answer (score 15):

Your question (and Anon's excellent answer) is part of [the SQL of islands and gaps](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/).  In this answer, I will try to examine the "row_number() magic" in detail.

I've made a simple example based on events in a ballgame.  For each event, we'd like to print the previous and next quarter related message:

```
create table TestTable (id int identity, event varchar(64));
insert TestTable values
    ('Start of Q1'),
    ('Free kick'),
    ('Goal'),
    ('End of Q1'),
    ('Start of Q2'),
    ('Penalty'),
    ('Miss'),
    ('Yellow card'),
    ('End of Q2');
```

Here's a query showing off the "row_number() magic" approach:

```
; with  grouped as
        (
        select  *
        ,       row_number() over (order by id) as rn1
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by case when event like '%of Q[1-4]' then 1 end 
                    order by id) as rn2
        from    TestTable
        )
,       order_in_group as
        (
        select  *
        ,       rn1-rn2 as group_nr
        ,       row_number() over (partition by rn1-rn2 order by id) as rank_asc
        ,       row_number() over (partition by rn1-rn2 order by id desc)
                    as rank_desc
        from    grouped
        )
select  *
,       lag(event, rank_asc) over (order by id) as last_event_of_prev_group
,       lead(event, rank_desc) over (order by id) as first_event_of_next_group
from    order_in_group
order by
        id
```

- The first CTE called "grouped" calculates two `row_number()`s.  The first is `1 2 3` for each row in the table.  The second `row_number()` places pause announcements in one list, and other events in a second list.   The difference between the two, `rn1 - rn2`, is unique for each section of the game.  It's helpful to check difference in the example output: it's in the `group_nr` column.  You'll see that each value corresponds to one section of the game.
- The second CTE called "order_in_group" determines the position of the current row within its island or gap.  For an island with 3 rows, the positions are `1 2 3` for the ascending order, and `3 2 1` for the descending order.
- Finally, we know enough to tell `lag()` and `lead()` how far to jump.  We have to lag `rank_asc` rows to find the final row of the previous section.  To find the first row of the next section, we have to lead `rank_desc` rows.

Hope this helps clarifying the "magic" of Gaps and Islands.  [Here is a working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64a73/1/0)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use LEAD/LAG.  You just need to precalculate how far to jump with a little ROW_NUMBER() magic.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE ( number int, price money, type varchar(2),
                   date date, time time)
INSERT @a VALUES
(23456,0.665,'SV','2014/02/02','08:00:02'),
(23457,1.3  ,'EC','2014/02/02','07:50:45'),
(23658,2.4  ,'EC','2014/02/02','07:50:45'),
(23660,2.4  ,'EC','2014/02/02','07:50:48'),
(23465,0.668,'SV','2014/02/02','07:36:34');

; WITH a AS (
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [date] DESC, [time] DESC) x, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
               CASE [type] WHEN 'SV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
               ORDER BY [date] DESC, [time] DESC) y 
     FROM @a)
 , b AS (
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x-y ORDER BY x ASC) z1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x-y ORDER BY x DESC) z2 
     FROM a)
SELECT *,
       CASE [type] WHEN 'SV' THEN 
           LAG(price,z1,price) OVER(PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY x) 
           ELSE LAG(price,z1,price) OVER(ORDER BY x) 
           END,
       CASE [type] WHEN 'SV' THEN 
           LEAD(price,z2,price) OVER(PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY x) 
           ELSE LEAD(price,z2,price) OVER(ORDER BY x) 
           END
FROM b
ORDER BY x
```

Comment: Great solution, but my RDBMS (Netezza) complains that the offset orgument to the lead function must be a "positive integer constant".

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way of achieving the same result, but using conditional max/min functions windowed over an ordinal. The ordinal can be be set up based on whatever columns fits the purpose, but in this case I believe the OP intends them to be `Date` and `Time`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
CREATE TABLE #t (
    Number INT, 
    Price MONEY, 
    Type CHAR(2),
    Date DATE,
    Time TIME(0)
);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES 
(23456, 0.666, 'SV', '2014/02/02', '10:00:02'),
(23457, 1.4  , 'EC', '2014/02/02', '09:50:45'),
(23658, 2.5  , 'EC', '2014/02/02', '09:50:45'),
(23660, 2.5  , 'EC', '2014/02/02', '09:50:48'),
(23465, 0.669, 'SV', '2014/02/02', '09:36:34'),
(23456, 0.665, 'SV', '2014/02/02', '08:00:02'),
(23457, 1.3  , 'EC', '2014/02/02', '07:50:45'),
(23658, 2.4  , 'EC', '2014/02/02', '07:50:45'),
(23660, 2.4  , 'EC', '2014/02/02', '07:50:48'),
(23465, 0.668, 'SV', '2014/02/02', '07:36:34'), -- which one of these?
(23465, 0.670, 'SV', '2014/02/02', '07:36:34'); -- 

WITH time_ordered AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time) AS ordinal FROM #t
)
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN Type = 'EC' 
    THEN MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = preceding_non_EC_ordinal THEN Price END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY preceding_non_EC_ordinal ORDER BY ordinal ASC) END AS preceding_price,
    CASE WHEN Type = 'EC'
    THEN MIN(CASE WHEN ordinal = following_non_EC_ordinal THEN Price END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY following_non_EC_ordinal ORDER BY ordinal DESC) END AS following_price
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type <> 'EC' THEN ordinal END) 
        OVER (ORDER BY ordinal ASC) AS preceding_non_EC_ordinal,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Type <> 'EC' THEN ordinal END) 
        OVER (ORDER BY ordinal DESC) AS following_non_EC_ordinal
    FROM time_ordered
) t
ORDER BY Date, Time
```

Note that the example given by the OP has been extended to show that interspersed sequences of `EC` yeild the intended result. The ambiguity introduced by the earliest two consecutive rows with type `SV` will in this case lead to the maximum value being picked. Setting up the ordinal to include the `Price` is a possible way to change this behavior.

An SQLFiddle can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/85117/1

Answer (score 0):

Anon's solution is wonderful and Andomar's explanation of it is also great, but there is a difficulty in using this approach in large data sets, namely that you can get conflicts in what Andomar called 'group_nr' (rn1 - rn2) where events from much earlier have the same group number.  This skews the rownumber calculation (which is by group_nr) and presents incorrect results when these conflicts arise.

Posting because I ran into this myself after working through this solution and finding errors.

my fix was to implement this version:

```
; with  grouped as
(
select  *
    ,       row_number() over (order by id) as rn1
    ,       row_number() over (
            partition by case when event like '%of Q[1-4]' then 1 end 
            order by id) as rn2
from    TestTable
)
,       order_in_group as
(
select  *
,       CASE 
          WHEN event like '%of Q[1-4]' THEN (-1*rn1-rn2)
          ELSE rn1 - rn2 
        END as group_nr
,       row_number() over (partition by rn1-rn2 order by id) as rank_asc
,       row_number() over (partition by rn1-rn2 order by id desc)
            as rank_desc
from    grouped
)
, final_grouping AS 
    (SELECT *
        ,       row_number() over (partition by group_nr order by jobid) AS rank_asc
        ,       row_number() over (partition by rn1-rn2 order by id desc) AS rank_desc
 FROM order_in_group
)
    select  *
    ,       lag(event, rank_asc) over (order by id) as last_event_of_prev_group
    ,       lead(event, rank_desc) over (order by id) as first_event_of_next_group
    from    final_grouping
    order by
        id
;
```

Changing the pause events' group_nr values to negatives makes sure there are no conflicts with large data sets.