# Is a cursor/recursion the only possible option here? Set based logic based on certain lag conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server, I have a table with 3 columns (timeseries) `data`, with date, `hour` beginning, `AwardStatus`.

The award status for the most part is randomly generated. There can be two options, Awarded or Not Awarded.

However, the business requirement is that we MUST print 'NotAwarded' for 3 consecutive rows if the status is NotAwarded, and 4 consecutive rows if the status is Awarded.

**Goal**: a new column `ShouldBe` details.

Once it meets the minimum requirements, then it checks that the current row's `AwardStatus` and continues to overwrite the logic.

**Question**: Is that possible in SQL without any kind of cursor/looping?

The picture in below as an example.

[image]

Here's an example:

```
AwardStatusMinimum  3       
AwardStatusMaximum  4       

Date    Hour    AwardStatus ShouldBe
--------------------------------------
1/1/2019    1   NotAwarded  NotAwarded
1/1/2019    2   NotAwarded  NotAwarded
1/1/2019    3   Awarded     NotAwarded
1/1/2019    4   Awarded     Awarded
1/1/2019    5   NotAwarded  Awarded
1/1/2019    6   NotAwarded  Awarded
1/1/2019    7   Awarded     Awarded
1/1/2019    8   NotAwarded  NotAwarded
1/1/2019    9   Awarded     NotAwarded
1/1/2019    10  Awarded     NotAwarded
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. No links to pictures, type the data sample and schema for us to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry! New here, Just added the code text!!

Comment: I think it could be a solution of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784189/lag-with-condition-in-sql-server

Comment: we expect something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a02b/1

Comment: Added to the original post, thanks horaciux, will make sure that's how I ask questions going forward.

Comment: For each separate record you must investigate all  previous record for to calculate what status would be. Records processing order is not defined. So no way to avoid iteration.

Comment: Excellent puzzle.  Bummer business requirement.

Comment: I agree, with Akina, too complex to avoid iteration.  You don't have to use a cursor, a while loop would work just setting the min hour/day in variables.  I did like the proposed solution's use of lag.  I hate that it got a down vote.  I never think about the windowing functions I'm always impressed when somebody uses them.

Comment: How would you use this in a while loop?

Comment: @Chemifesto . . . Why not just assign groups of 3 and 4, disregarding the current values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since recursion was mentioned.

Here's a solution that uses a recursive CTE.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (
>   [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
>   [Hour] INT NOT NULL, 
>   [AwardStatus] VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Table1
>  ([Date], [Hour], [AwardStatus])
> VALUES
>  ('2019-01-01', 1, 'NotAwarded'),      
>  ('2019-01-01', 2, 'NotAwarded'),     
>  ('2019-01-01', 3, 'Awarded'),
>  ('2019-01-01', 4, 'Awarded'),
>  ('2019-01-01', 5, 'NotAwarded'),
>  ('2019-01-01', 6, 'NotAwarded'),
>  ('2019-01-01', 7, 'Awarded'),
>  ('2019-01-01', 8, 'NotAwarded'),
>  ('2019-01-01', 9, 'Awarded'),
>  ('2019-01-01', 10, 'Awarded');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> ;with CTE_DATA AS 
> (
>   select *
>   , dense_rank() 
>     over (order by cast([Date] as date)) as grp
>   , row_number() 
>     over (partition by cast([Date] as date) order by [Hour]) as rn
>   from Table1
> )
> , RCTE_AWARDS as
> (
>   select [Date], [Hour]
>   , AwardStatus
>   , grp
>   , rn
>   , 1 as Lvl
>   , AwardStatus AS CalcStatus
>   from CTE_DATA
>   where rn = 1
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select t.[Date], t.[Hour]
>   , t.AwardStatus
>   , t.grp
>   , t.rn
>   , case
>     when (c.lvl < 3)
>       or (c.lvl < 4 and c.CalcStatus = 'Awarded')
>     then c.lvl+1
>     else 1
>     end
>   , case 
>     when (c.lvl = 3 and c.CalcStatus = 'NotAwarded')
>       or (c.lvl = 4)
>     then t.AwardStatus
>     else c.CalcStatus
>     end
>   from RCTE_AWARDS c
>   join CTE_DATA t 
>     on t.grp = c.grp
>    and t.rn = c.rn + 1
> )
> select [Date], [Hour], AwardStatus
> , CalcStatus AS NewAwardStatus
> from RCTE_AWARDS
> order by [Date], [Hour]
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                    | Hour | AwardStatus | NewAwardStatus
> :---------------------- | ---: | :---------- | :-------------
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    1 | NotAwarded  | NotAwarded    
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    2 | NotAwarded  | NotAwarded    
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    3 | Awarded     | NotAwarded    
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    4 | Awarded     | Awarded       
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    5 | NotAwarded  | Awarded       
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    6 | NotAwarded  | Awarded       
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    7 | Awarded     | Awarded       
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    8 | NotAwarded  | NotAwarded    
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |    9 | Awarded     | NotAwarded    
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |   10 | Awarded     | NotAwarded
> ```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c79e5f6a79ae3ed0a0ef343fe2294af)*

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to do it without using cursor.

```
 declare @date date
 declare @hour int
 declare @CurrentStatus varchar(50)

 set @CurrentStatus=''

 while exists(select * from Awards where ShouldBe is null)
 begin
     select top 1 @date=[date], @hour=[hour] , @CurrentStatus=AwardStatus
     from Awards 
     where [ShouldBe] is null 
     order by [date],[hour]

     if(@CurrentStatus='Awarded')
     begin
         update top(4) Awards
         set ShouldBe=@CurrentStatus
         where [date]=@date and [hour]>=@hour
     end
     else 
         begin
         update top(3) Awards
         set ShouldBe=@CurrentStatus
         where [date]=@date and [hour]>=@hour
     end

 end
```