# One of the previous row value with condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm generating a table like this in BigQuery with standard GoogleSQL:

| sessionID | hitNumber | ListViewID | Position | Sponsored | isClick | impressions | clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa20230425 | 1 | aaa20230425-1 | 2 | 1 | false | 1 | 0 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 6 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 7 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 8 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 9 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 10 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 11 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 |
| aaa20230425 | 2 | aaa20230425-2 | 2 | 1 | true | 0 | 1 |
| ccc20230425 | 1 | ccc20230425-1 | 0 | 1 | false | 1 | 0 |
| ddd20230425 | 17 | ddd20230425-17 | 1 | 1 | false | 1 | 0 |

My code:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(fullVisitorID, CAST(visitID AS string), date) AS sessionID,
    hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
    CONCAT( fullvisitorID, CAST(visitId AS STRING), date, hits.hitNumber ) AS ListViewID,
    product.productListPosition AS Position,
    customDimensions.value AS Sponsored,
    (CASE
         WHEN product.isClick = TRUE THEN TRUE
         ELSE FALSE
     END) AS isClick,
    SUM(
  IF
    (product.isImpression, 1,0)) AS impressions,
  SUM(
  IF
    (product.isClick,1,0)) AS clicks
FROM
    `Table`,
UNNEST (hits) AS hits,
UNNEST (hits.product) AS product,
UNNEST (product.customDimensions) AS customDimensions
WHERE
    product.productListName IN ("searchpage", "categorypage")
    AND customDimensions.index = 68
GROUP BY
    SessionID, hitNumber, ListViewID, Position,
    Sponsored, isClick
```

I need to create an additional column "parent_ListViewID" which:

- if isClick = false, then "parent_ListViewID" value is from "ListViewID" column of the same row
- if isClick = true, then "parent_ListViewID" value is from "ListViewID" column of the *previous latest row* with isClick = false and same SessionID

Given the example above, I need to have a table like this:

| sessionID | hitNumber | ListViewID | Position | Sponsored | isClick | impressions | clicks | parent_ListViewID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa20230425 | 1 | aaa20230425-1 | 2 | 1 | false | 1 | 0 | aaa20230425-1 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 6 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 | bbb20230425-1 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 7 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 | bbb20230425-1 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 8 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 | bbb20230425-1 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 9 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 | bbb20230425-1 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 10 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 | bbb20230425-1 |
| bbb20230425 | 1 | bbb20230425-1 | 11 | 0 | false | 1 | 0 | bbb20230425-1 |
| aaa20230425 | 2 | aaa20230425-2 | 2 | 1 | true | 0 | 1 | aaa20230425-1 |
| ccc20230425 | 1 | ccc20230425-1 | 0 | 1 | false | 1 | 0 | ccc20230425-1 |
| ddd20230425 | 17 | ddd20230425-17 | 1 | 1 | false | 1 | 0 | ddd20230425-17 |

I've tried a solution with LAG() here but couldn't get it to work:
[Lag() with condition in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784189/lag-with-condition-in-sql-server)

I've also tried a few solutions with last_value, but failed as well - it returns last ListViewID value across all values with the same sessionID, not just from the previous rows.

Comment: You need an ordering column in your table like timestamp to use `LAG()` function.

Comment: @Jaytiger, I have a "hitNumber" column, which is sorted within sessionID

Comment: If the answer works for you, it would be nice if you mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  -- put your sample data here
)
-- query starts here
SELECT *,
       IF (
         isClick IS TRUE,
         LAST_VALUE(IF(isClick IS FALSE, ListViewID, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w,
         ListViewID
       ) AS parent_ListViewID
  FROM sample_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY sessionID ORDER BY hitNumber);
```

**Query result**

[image]

- assume that `hitNumber` is `INT64` type.

Comment: I'll be playing around it further, but at first glance it seems to work correctly. Thank you, Jaytiger!