# BigQuery - GA - Select LAST values from other table with multi match

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics

What I'm trying to do in BigQuery using data from Google Analytics:

1. get the list of product impressions and clicks from Google Analytics, together with additional data (productListName, productListPosition, Test etc.) - aka "listTable"
2. get the list of transactions, that are associated with those clicks - aka "transTable"
3. populate the missing field values in "transTable" with values from "listTable"
   -- Test

   -- productListName

   -- productListPosition

   -- Sponsored

   -- searchResultType
4. Match those missing values by a combination of *date, fullVisitorID, visitID* (I assume those are how you define *sessionID*) and productSKU.
5. Given that there may be multiple matches, I'd take the *last value* (ordered by *hitNumber*)
6. Combine "listTable" and "transTable"

**I'm having a problem with steps 3 to 5**, so I've set the required values as NULL for now in the "transTable".

Here is my code so far:

```
WITH
  listTable AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      date,
      fullVisitorID,
      visitID,
      (
      SELECT
        value
      FROM
        UNNEST(hits.customdimensions)
      WHERE
        INDEX = 58
      GROUP BY
        value ) AS Test,
      hits.hitNumber,
      CASE
        WHEN product.isImpression = TRUE THEN "Impression"
        WHEN product.isClick = TRUE THEN "Click"
    END
      AS Action,
      productListName,
      product.productListPosition AS productListPosition,
      (
      SELECT
        value
      FROM
        UNNEST(product.customdimensions)
      WHERE
        INDEX = 68
      GROUP BY
        value ) AS Sponsored,
      (
      SELECT
        value
      FROM
        UNNEST(product.customdimensions)
      WHERE
        INDEX = 76
      GROUP BY
        value ) AS searchResultType,
      product.productSKU,
      product.productPrice / 1000000 AS Price
    FROM
      `ga_sessions_20230603`,
      UNNEST (hits) AS hits,
      UNNEST (hits.product) AS product
    WHERE
      productListName IN ( "searchpage",
        "categorypage",
        "dropdown_initial",
        "dropdown_results" )
      AND ( product.isImpression = TRUE
        OR product.isClick = TRUE ) )
  ORDER BY
    date,
    fullVisitorID ASC,
    visitID ASC,
    hitNumber ASC,
    productListPosition ASC ),

  transTable AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorID,
    visitID,
    NULL AS Test,
    hits.hitNumber,
    CASE
      WHEN hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6" THEN "Purchase"
  END
    AS Action,
    NULL AS productListName,
    NULL AS productListPosition,
    NULL AS Sponsored,
    NULL AS searchResultType,
    product.productSKU,
    product.productPrice / 1000000 AS Price
  FROM
    `ga_sessions_20230603`,
    UNNEST (hits) AS hits,
    UNNEST (hits.product) AS product
  WHERE
    hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6"
    AND CONCAT(date, fullVisitorID, visitID) IN (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT CONCAT(date, fullVisitorID, visitID)
    FROM
      listTable
    WHERE
      Action = "Click" )
  ORDER BY
    date,
    fullVisitorID ASC,
    visitID ASC,
    hitNumber ASC )

SELECT
  *
FROM
  listTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  transTable
```

I think I can use **LAST_VALUE()**, but can't figure out how to use it properly - it seems similar to the problem I've had earlier:
[One of the previous row value with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76100331/one-of-the-previous-row-value-with-condition)

Not sure if I can use **LAG()** here, after *combining tables*.

Could you help me out, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I've solved my problem exactly like here:
[One of the previous row value with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76100331/one-of-the-previous-row-value-with-condition)

```
WITH
  listTable AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      date,
      fullVisitorID,
      visitID,
      (
      SELECT
        value
      FROM
        UNNEST(hits.customdimensions)
      WHERE
        INDEX = 58
      GROUP BY
        value ) AS Test,
      hits.hitNumber,
      CASE
        WHEN product.isImpression = TRUE THEN "Impression"
        WHEN product.isClick = TRUE THEN "Click"
    END
      AS Action,
      productListName,
      product.productListPosition AS productListPosition,
      (
      SELECT
        value
      FROM
        UNNEST(product.customdimensions)
      WHERE
        INDEX = 68
      GROUP BY
        value ) AS Sponsored,
      (
      SELECT
        value
      FROM
        UNNEST(product.customdimensions)
      WHERE
        INDEX = 76
      GROUP BY
        value ) AS searchResultType,
      product.productSKU,
      product.productPrice / 1000000 AS Price,
      CONCAT(date, fullVisitorID, visitID, productSKU) AS listKey
    FROM
      `gap2-144306.73525272.ga_sessions_20230603`,
      UNNEST (hits) AS hits,
      UNNEST (hits.product) AS product
    WHERE
      productListName IN ( "searchpage",
        "categorypage",
        "dropdown_initial",
        "dropdown_results" )
      AND ( product.isImpression = TRUE
        OR product.isClick = TRUE )
      AND (
      SELECT
        value
      FROM
        UNNEST(`gap2-144306.73525272.ga_sessions_20230603`.customDimensions)
      WHERE
        INDEX = 12
      GROUP BY
        value ) NOT IN ("business",
        "robot",
        "wholesale"))
  ORDER BY
    date,
    fullVisitorID ASC,
    visitID ASC,
    hitNumber ASC,
    productListPosition ASC ),


  ini_transTable AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorID,
    visitID,
    "NULL" AS Test,
    hits.hitNumber,
    CASE
      WHEN hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6" THEN "Purchase"
  END
    AS Action,
    "NULL" AS productListName,
    NULL AS productListPosition,
    "NULL" AS Sponsored,
    "NULL" AS searchResultType,
    product.productSKU,
    product.productPrice / 1000000 AS Price,
    CONCAT(date, fullVisitorID, visitID, productSKU) AS transKey
  FROM
    `gap2-144306.73525272.ga_sessions_20230603`,
    UNNEST (hits) AS hits,
    UNNEST (hits.product) AS product
  WHERE
    hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6"
    AND CONCAT(date, fullVisitorID, visitID, productSKU) IN (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT listKey
    FROM
      listTable
    WHERE
      Action = "Click" )
  ORDER BY
    date,
    fullVisitorID ASC,
    visitID ASC,
    hitNumber ASC ),


  ini_uTable AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    listTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    ini_transTable
  ORDER BY
    date,
    fullVisitorID ASC,
    visitID ASC,
    hitNumber ASC),

    
  uTable AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorID,
    visitID,
  IF
    (Action = "Purchase", LAST_VALUE(
      IF
        (Action != "Purchase", Test, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY listKey ORDER BY hitNumber ASC), Test) AS Test,
    hitNumber,
    Action,
  IF
    (Action = "Purchase", LAST_VALUE(
      IF
        (Action != "Purchase", productListName, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY listKey ORDER BY hitNumber ASC), productListName) AS productListName,
  IF
    (Action = "Purchase", LAST_VALUE(
      IF
        (Action != "Purchase", productListPosition, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY listKey ORDER BY hitNumber ASC), productListPosition) AS productListPosition,
  IF
    (Action = "Purchase", LAST_VALUE(
      IF
        (Action != "Purchase", Sponsored, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY listKey ORDER BY hitNumber ASC), Sponsored) AS Sponsored,
  IF
    (Action = "Purchase", LAST_VALUE(
      IF
        (Action != "Purchase", searchResultType, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY listKey ORDER BY hitNumber ASC), searchResultType) AS searchResultType,
    productSKU,
    Price,
    listKey
  FROM
    ini_uTable
  ORDER BY
    date,
    fullVisitorID ASC,
    visitID ASC,
    hitNumber ASC )
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant solution than my brute-forcing through the problem.
I'll appreciate any suggestions.