Previous Values at Different Partitions
I have a following table.

You can create this table using these scripts.

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MonthlySales', N'U') IS NOT NULL  
   DROP TABLE [dbo].MonthlySales;  


GO
CREATE TABLE MonthlySales
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
SaleYear SMALLINT NOT NULL,
SaleQuarter TINYINT NOT NULL,
SalePrice DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
SaleDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO MonthlySales
(SaleYear,SaleQuarter,SalePrice,SaleDateTime)
SELECT 2007,1,202.10,'2007-01-01 11:00:03'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2007,1,201.10,'2007-03-22 16:22:13'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2007,3,982.32,'2007-08-15 14:12:11'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2007,4,762.25, '2007-11-11 00:37:19'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2007,1,210.32,'2007-01-31 13:22:15'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2007,1,223.25,'2007-03-01 22:10:43'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2007,4,843.98, '2007-12-24 09:00:39'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2007,3,843.11, '2007-09-21 07:13:26'


It's basically a hypothetical table with the sample sales of Year 2007. For simplicity sake there is no other year sales recorded in this table. Sales may not happen in every quarter of 2007.
I need the previous month sale (which I can easily get using Lag Function of SQL Server I am using 2019 version).
I also need to derive Previous Sale Quarter.
Is there a way I can write the Lag function or any other function so I can get achieve the result within the same query?
if I write the following query
Select * 
,LAG(SalePrice) OVER (PARTITION BY SaleQuarter ORDER BY SaleDateTime) AS Previous_SalePrice

,LAG(SaleQuarter) OVER (PARTITION BY SaleQuarter ORDER BY SaleDateTime,SaleQuarter) AS PreviousQuarter
From MonthlySales
Order by SaleDateTime

It gives me the following result set.

What I want is,

Unfortunately It is impossible for me to get the PrevoiusQuarter on this data set using LAG Function.
However if I write a cTe SQL statements separately I can achieve this.
;with CTE AS (
Select * 
,LAG(SalePrice) OVER (PARTITION BY SaleQuarter ORDER BY SaleDateTime) AS Previous_SalePrice
From MonthlySales
)
,ANother_CTE AS (
Select SaleYear,SaleQuarter,LAG(SaleQuarter) OVER (PARTITION BY SaleYear ORDER BY SaleQuarter) AS PreviousQuarter From MonthlySales
GROUP BY SaleYear,SaleQuarter
)
Select a.*,b.PreviousQuarter FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN ANother_CTE B
ON A.SaleYear=B.SaleYear
AND A.SaleQuarter=b.SaleQuarter

This is a single SQL Statement but I had to use 2 CTEs. I was wondering if I can do something so I can achieve everything without a subquery/CTE.
Edit: I have dropped the SaleMonthNum field after the comments from @ThomA. This will help understand the question better I hope.

LAG gives you the value of the prior row, not the (aggregate of the) prior range.

I suspect you need to give more examples here, What would you expect if there were 2 sales in quarter 3, for example?

@ThomA - How can I get the aggregate of the prior range?

@Thom A It is just easier to share a solution this way. Less cut and paste. Also, I am not allowed to use company database resources to solve SO problems during my breaks. If I need to use a fiddle I might as well share it.

This seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784189/lag-with-condition-in-sql-server

You're likely going to need some preaggregation. I'm against posting an answer until I'm certain of the requirement, which would need additional sample data.

How do you want the results when examples for 2006 and 2008 are added? I suspect you want partition by SaleYear,SaleQuarter.  Also, you seem to have skipped 2007 quarter 2.

@BarMcEndree - Yes I have skipped quarter 2 and I've limited it to 2007 only for simplicity. If I add 2006 and 2008 it gets complicated.

You can use Case to detect duplicated SaleQuarter numbers
Select * 
,LAG(SalePrice) OVER (ORDER BY SaleMonthNum) AS Previous_SalePrice
,LAG(SaleMonthNum) OVER (ORDER BY SaleMonthNum) AS Previous_SaleMonthNum
,CASE LAG(SaleQuarter) OVER (ORDER BY SaleQuarter) WHEN SaleQuarter THEN NULL
  ELSE LAG(SaleQuarter) OVER (ORDER BY SaleQuarter) END AS PreviousQuarter
From MonthlySales


Not sure this would give the results the OP is after. Their example data isn't ideal, as the only row that have 2 rows for the same quarter is the first quarter. I suspect for latter rows they wouldn't want NULL be the actual prior quarter.

@Thom A  True. We will need more example records to find the ideal solution.

Using Lag() with condition in sql server
I applied your example and added a 2nd row for SaleQuarter #3.
with  grouped as
        (
        select  *,       row_number() over (order by id) as rn1
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by SaleYear,SaleQuarter 
                    order by id) as rn2
        from    MonthlySales
        ),  order_in_group as
        (
        select  *,  rn1-rn2 as group_nr
        ,       row_number() over (partition by rn1-rn2 order by id) as rank_asc
        from    grouped
        )
select  ID, SaleYear, SaleQuarter, SaleMonthNum, SalePrice,
        lag(SaleQuarter, rank_asc) over (order by id) as PreviousQuarter
from    order_in_group
order by  id

fiddle



ID
SaleYear
SaleQuarter
SaleMonthNum
SalePrice
PreviousQuarter




1
2007
1
1
202.10
null


2
2007
1
3
201.10
null


3
2007
3
8
982.32
1


4
2007
3
8
900.32
1


5
2007
4
11
762.25
3



